# Creating Visualforce account information form with account lookup

Tags: visualforce, lookup, account

I am creating a VF form with account information input fields as well as other custom fields.  I would like to create a lookup field for the user to select the account to work in.  I am able to create a drop-down list of accounts, but the preference is a lookup field rather than the account list.  Is this possible, if so can someone give me an example.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non-persisted instance of an object that has a lookup field to an `Account` to provide the field:

```
public with sharing class YourController {
    public Contact c {
        get {
            if (c == null) c = new Contact();
            return c;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

and then Visualforce will render a lookup field:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Whatever Label You Want to Use"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!c.AccountId}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

and in later logic in the controller you can then use the `c.AccountId` value that is selected.

Comment: @swifttest1 -- N.B. this is a powerful approach that can be leveraged into other use cases, for example, to provide the SFDC date picker to non-Sobject field inputs

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using a similar approach as Keith.  I created an account in the controller strictly for lookup, and used the ParentID of that account to query and pull in the account the end user is working in.